# How to merge some table cells in Reactable

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I'm trying to create a `reactable` that will display statistics for a large number of categorical variables. The table should show the following columns: variable name, categories of variable, categories frequency, percentage, number of valid, and number of missing values.I would like to merge some table cells so that the values are not duplicated. I would like to merge: variable name, Valid Count and Missing Count. I could do this with java script, but I don't know that language.

This is the code I'm working on:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reachable)



calculate_summary <- function(x) {
  data_summary <- data.frame(Category = x) %>%
    count(Category, name = "Frequency") %>%
    mutate(Percent = (Frequency / sum(Frequency)) * 100,
           Valid_Count = sum(!is.na(Category)),
           Missing_Count = sum(is.na(Category))) %>%
    select(Category, Frequency, Percent, Valid_Count, Missing_Count)
  
  return(data_summary)
}



# Function to create the reactable
create_reactable <- function(data) {
  data_summary <- lapply(data, calculate_summary)
  combined_data <- do.call(rbind, data_summary)
  reactable(
    combined_data,striped = TRUE, resizable = TRUE, wrap = FALSE,
    style = list(
      fontFamily = "Helvetica"),
    
    columns = list(
      Category = colDef(name = "Category"),
      Frequency = colDef(name = "Count"),
      Percent = colDef(name = "Percent %"),
      Valid_Count = colDef(name = "Valid Count"),
      Missing_Count = colDef(name = "Missing Count")
    ),
    showPagination = TRUE
  )
}

# Example data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  Variable = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", NA),
  Proba = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", NA)
  )
  


# Create the reactable using the function
reactable_data <- create_reactable(data)

# Display the reactable
reactable_data
```

With that code I get the following table design:

[image]

However, I would like to merge some cells.The table would look like this.

[image]

thanks!

Comment: What do yo mean with "merge"? Actually, there are no duplicates by "variable name, Valid Count and Missing Count", since there isn't even a column called "variable name "and also in the row names they are unique. Please provide the final expected output without black bars and show also how it shall look like for `Proba`.

Comment: Black bars in the table are places where there should not be a value. It is absolutely the same thing for the Proba variable. Run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possibility.

[image]

You could get this by using:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reactable)

calculate_summary <- function(x) {
    data_summary <- data.frame(Category = x) %>%
        count(Category, name = "Frequency") %>%
        mutate(Percent = (Frequency / sum(Frequency)) * 100,
               Valid_Count = ifelse(Category == "C", sum(!is.na(Category)), NA),
               Missing_Count = ifelse(Category == "C", sum(is.na(Category)), NA)) %>%
        select(Category, Frequency, Percent, Valid_Count, Missing_Count) 
    
    return(data_summary)
}

# Function to create the reactable
create_reactable <- function(data) {
    data_summary <- lapply(data, calculate_summary)
    combined_data <- do.call(rbind, data_summary) |> 
        tibble::rownames_to_column("Name") |> 
        mutate(Name = ifelse(Category != "C", "", Name)) |> 
        mutate(Name = gsub("\\..*","",Name)) 
    
    reactable(
        combined_data,striped = TRUE, resizable = TRUE, wrap = FALSE,
        style = list(
            fontFamily = "Helvetica"),
        
        columns = list(
            Category = colDef(name = "Category"),
            Frequency = colDef(name = "Count"),
            Percent = colDef(name = "Percent %"),
            Valid_Count = colDef(name = "Valid Count"),
            Missing_Count = colDef(name = "Missing Count")
        ),
        showPagination = TRUE
    )
}

# Example data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
    Variable = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", NA),
    Proba = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", NA)
)

# Create the reactable using the function
reactable_data <- create_reactable(data)

# Display the reactable
reactable_data
```